# Does the Nikon D40x support SDHC class 10 and 6 cards?

Tags: nikon-d40, sdhc

Does the Nikon D40x support SDHC class 10 and 6 cards?

Do you know whats the list of supported cards by the D40x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [DPreview](http://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/slrs/nikon_d40x) it supports SD and SDHC cards. This includes all the classes of these cards.

The classes only differ from each other regarding write speeds. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speed_Class_Rating) is more information on that.

As the D40x can not record video, a class 10 card is not necessary. A lower speed card is sufficient to take pictures.